# Как уловить исключения в списках при выводе?

Tags: python-3.x, список, списки

При парсинге сайта иногда отсутствуют result2 и result3 и записывается только result1, можно ли добавить условие на существование этих элементов и если их нету заполнить их?

```
  for row  in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
          cols = row.find_all('td')

          projects.append({
            'result1': cols[1].span.text,
            'result2': cols[2].span.text,
            'result3': cols[3].span.text
          })
```

Comment: Что в вашем `projects` и что значит отсутствуют `result2` и `result3`? Отсутствуют значения, или у вас еще и переменные такие есть? Если просто отстутствуют значения - то можно. А вообще, добавьте пожалуйста больше кода, касающегося этого места. И да, в питоне индексация начинается не с единиицы, а с 0(это я так, на всякий случай).

Comment: И вообще лучше проходится циклом по вашему `cols`

Comment: Блин сори не написал, 'projects' это список .  В список я закидываю словарь с именами 'result1' и 'result2' и значениями из парсинга 'cols'. т.е  на сайте может быть как все три этих значений либо только одно. Я хочу добавить условие, когда 'cols[2].span.text' и 'cols[3].span.text'  не найдены то присвоить 'result2' какое нибудь значение.

Comment: `result1`, `result2`, `result3` — плохие имена. Вместо словаря, можно просто кортеж передать: `project.append(('первая колонка', 'вторая', 'третья'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить колонки со значением по умолчанию, если их не хватает:

```
NCOLS = 3
cols = [span.text for span in row.select('td span')]  # CSS selector
cols += ['default'] * (NCOLS - len(cols))  # pad to NCOLS if necessary
projects.append(dict(zip(['result'+str(i) for i in range(1, NCOLS+1)], cols)))
```

Связанный вопрос: чтобы выполнить череду вычислений, когда промежуточные результаты могут отсутствовать, см. [Maybe "kind-of" monad in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8507200/4279).

Comment: Хорошо, буду пробывать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом:

```
cols = row.find_all('td')
result1 = cols[0].span.text
result2 = cols[1].span.text
result3 = cols[2].span.text
if result2 and result3:
    projects.append({
        'result1': result1,
        'result2': result2,
        'result3': result3
         })
elif result2:
    projects.append({
        'result1': result1,
        'result2': result2,
        'result3': 'some data'
         })
elif result3:
     projects.append({
        'result1': result1,
        'result2': 'some another data',
        'result3': result3
         })
else:
    projects.append({
        'result1': result1,
        'result2': 'some another data',
        'result3': 'some data'
         })
```

Это не очень хорошее решение, но в вашем случае - сгодится. Вообще лучше проходится циклом по вашим `cols`, а там где вы обрабатываете результаты - не опираться на обязательное присутствие ключей в этом словаре.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row  in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
      cols = row.find_all('td')

      projects.append({
        'result1': cols[1].span.text if cols[1].span.text else "default",
        'result2': cols[2].span.text if cols[2].span.text else "default",
        'result3': cols[3].span.text if cols[3].span.text else "default"
      })
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение)